# webdriverio - not able to find element with class name

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

I am trying find an element with

```
let selector = "[class='count-stats']";
console.log(browser.element(selector));
```

Getting an error with

```
{ type: 'NoSuchElement',
  message: 'An element could not be located on the page using the given search p
arameters.',
  state: 'failure',
  sessionId: 'd16e8f18e203d7d862d36bcb29f86cfa',
  value: null,
  selector: '[class=count-stats]' }
```

There is a `div` with class name `count-stats` on a page.

**How do I find an element with class name ?**

Comment: `".count-stats"` ?

Comment: @JonasW. tried but still not working. same error.

Comment: Could it be that your div and it's class could be finding another element or also is possibly hidden on the page until something happens? Are you certain that the element is visible first? Try and "Assert" that the element isVisible then try accessing it. You could also "waitForVisible". If your script is too fast it might be looking for it before it's actually present and able to be interacted with.

Answer (score 1):

I've had success with the following formats:

`let selector = '[class="count-stats"]';`
and
`let selector = '.count-stats';`

With the first example, I swapped the quotes and single quotes around as the error message you posted didn't look quite right (`selector: '[class=count-stats]'`).

If those don't work, are you sure the element you're trying to interact with is visible?

Answer (score 0):

For me your example works. Can you provide a snippet of your html code?